# I want to break print page as according to data automatically. The printing data may changes. Is there any way of doing it in media in html,css or js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using mobile printer for receipt purpose. Paper size is  @page {
     size: 80mm 240mm;
If I take print for this, it will take whole page for print and this is waste of paper.

So, I need to automatically detect the data inside the page and break print page according to data.

Comment: Hi, @sd c, welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to better help you, we'll need more information. Adding some of your code to the question will go a long way, for example.

Comment: Why did you tag this C#, but ask your question is about html/css/javascript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Printing